# React + Vite : Problem with path aliases, not recognising the @ character

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I'm starting a project with React using Vite and I have a problem with the path aliases if I want to use the @ character.

This is my code:

**tsconfig.json**

```json
....
"baseUrl": "./src",
/* Paths */
"paths": {
   "@/*": ["./*"]
}
...
```

**vite.config.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import * as path from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/'),
            services: `${path.resolve(__dirname, './src/services/')}`
        }
    }
});
```

**MyComponent.tsx**

It works:

```js
import { DB } from 'services/db';
```

Not working:

```js
import { DB } from '@services/db';
```

Error: `Cannot find module '@services/db' or its corresponding type declarations`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably would work using

```
import { DB } from '@/services/db';
```

Because you are mapping the `@` character with the `./` path.